# Java8 - Converting an async interface into a synchronous one

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, blocking, thread-sleep

I am working with an external lib that defines a `Monitor` class that accepts a `Sensor` interface and sends results into it periodically:

```
public interface Sensor {
    // called by the monitor when new results are available
    void updatedResult(double result);

    // called when done sending results
    void done();
}
```

I have implemented the sensor as follows:

```
public class SensorImpl implements Sensor {
    private boolean isDone;
    private List<double> data;

    public SensorImpl() {
        this.isDone = false;
        this.data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    void updatedResult(double result);
        this.data.add(result);
    }

    @Override
    void done() {
        this.isDone = true;
    }

    public boolean isDoneReceiving() {
        return this.isDone;
    }

    public List<double> getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

And am running my program like this (simplified):

```
  public void run() {

    // initialize a sensor instance
    SensorImpl sensor = new SensorImpl();

    // initialize a monitor that streams data into the sensor (async)
    Monitor monitor = new Monitor(sensor);

    // start monitoring the sensor
    monitor.start();

    // block until done
    while (!sensor.isDoneReceiving()) {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }

    // retrieve data and continue processing...
    List<double> data = sensor.getData();

    // ...
}
```

While this works, it feels icky to be blocking on a thread with sleep, and I'm looking for a way to make this cleaner. This becomes even more relevant when applying executors to monitor multiple sensors of various types in parallel. Any assistance will be appreciated.

## UPDATE:

I ended up implementing `Future<List<Double>>`, which allowed me to simply call `List<Double> results = sensor.get();`, which blocks until all results are available.

```
public class SensorImpl implements Sensor {

    // ...
    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch;

    public SensorImpl() {
        this.countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void done() {
        // when called by async processes, decrement the latch (and release it)
        this.countDownLatch.countDown();
    }

    // ...

}
```

Here's a great answer that provided good reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2180534/187907

Comment: Make your `done` implementation `countDown` a `CountDownLatch` of 1. Make your `isDoneReceiving` implementation `await` on that same `CountDownLatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, several classes from the `concurrent` package can help you, such as `Semaphore`, `CoundDownLatch`, `CyclicBarrier` or even a `BlockingQueue`, where you would block on the queue and wait for the other threads to put values in it when finished.

A CountDownLatch is most probably best suited for your specific example.
Perhaps you can view [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184147/countdownlatch-vs-semaphore), it has a nice overview about Semaphore and CountDownLatch: