# I can not bring out any value from GraphRequest().executeAsync()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the graph api of facebook for android. I can not bring out any value from GraphRequest([...]).executeAsync(). So the return string is always empty

```
public String getPost(){
        new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "me?fields=friends,name", null, HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject();
                        try {
                            friends = object.getJSONObject("friends").getJSONObject("summary").getString("total_count");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        };

                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();

        return friends;
}
```

Comment: Well of course, it's an async call. It's literally called `executeAsync`. `friends` isn't set when you return, it's set in `onCompleted` which will be called some time in the future, specifically when that `GraphRequest` is completed (hence the name `onCompleted`). It's like asking why a response to your letter didn't magically appear in your hand after putting the letter into a mailbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrapping an asynchronous computation into a synchronous (blocking) computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180419/wrapping-an-asynchronous-computation-into-a-synchronous-blocking-computation)

Answer (score 0):

`return friends` will return the default `friends`. you are not getting the behavior of `executeAsync()` here. `executeAsync()` will run asynchronously and method will return immediately after scheduling the `executeAsync()` Task.

The data i.e `friends` is modifying inside the callback method so you have to return it from  `onCompleted()`.

To return data you can use a callback interface See [How to define callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398363/how-to-define-callbacks-in-android).