# How do I listen to an event on an object from within a WCF web service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest

I have a web service that instantiates an object, subscribes to an event on that object, and then calls a function on the object which will lead to the event being fired. Is there a way to wait for the event to fire so I can get the results from the EventArgs in order to pass those results as the results of the web service?

Comment: Are the invocation of the method and the firing of the event synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: That is to say calling the method on the object kicks off an asynchronous process that will eventually finish and fire the event. Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some kind of synchronization primitive associated with the event (such as a ManualResetEventSlim) that gets signalled in the event handler. Then your request thread can wait on the event and collect the results after the event has occurred and generate the response

However, a more natural model may be to create the service as an asynchronous service and only complete the processing when the async operation completes - I created [a sample of this](http://www.dotnetconsult.co.uk/weblog2/PermaLink,guid,83b06d32-1fa8-4757-b062-c2e1766a5525.aspx) a while back

Comment: That sounds similar to what I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475617/wrapping-an-asynchronous-method-synchronously-in-c-sharp but that uses AutoResetEvent. What's the difference between AutoResetEvent, ManualResetEvent, and ManualResetEventSlim?

Comment: AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent are wrappers over the underlying kernel object whereas ManualResetEventSlim is a fully managed event (so a lot more lightweight). ManualResetEventSlim is only available in .NET 4.0 however. AutoResetEvents reset themselves to non-signalled after the waiter wakes up. Manual events must be manually reset